# Does \end command issue a \vfill

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

Does `\end` command issue a `\vfill` command? I notice that in plain TeX, you have a `\bye` that issues it but after some experimentation I think `\end` also issues a `\vfill`, which is rather confusing.

Example:

```
Case 1:
Hello World\vfil
Hello World\end
```

---

```
Case 2:
Hello World\vfill
Hello World\end
```

Comparing the above two cases, we note that Case 1 place both lines of texts normally while in Case 2 TeX placed the second line of text in the middle. Now, if `\end` did not come with a `\vfill`, the first case would have also place the second line of text in the middle. This is where I am confused.

Comment: According to tex by topic "The \end command – which is only allowed in external vertical mode – terminates a TEX job, but only if the main vertical list is empty and \deadcycles = 0. If this is
not the case the combination \hbox{}\vfill\penalty−2^30
is appended, which forces the output routine to act."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308404/71471) in Don knuth words (The TeXbook, page 264)

> When TeX sees an \end command, it terminates the job only if the main
>   vertical list has been entirely output and if \deadcycles=0. Otherwise
>   it inserts the equivalent of
>
> ```
>               \line{} \vfill \penalty-'10000000000
> ```
>
> into the main vertical list, and prepares to read the `\end' token again. This has
>   the effect of invoking the output routine repeatedly until everything
>   has been shipped out. In particular, the last column of two-column
>   format will not be lost.

Answer (score 6):

in `tex.web` you find

```
@<Declare act...@>=
function its_all_over:boolean; {do this when \.{\\end} or \.{\\dump} occurs}
label exit;
begin if privileged then
  begin if (page_head=page_tail)and(head=tail)and(dead_cycles=0) then
    begin its_all_over:=true; return;
    end;
  back_input; {we will try to end again after ejecting residual material}
  tail_append(new_null_box);
  width(tail):=hsize;
  tail_append(new_glue(fill_glue));
  tail_append(new_penalty(-@'10000000000));@/
  build_page; {append \.{\\hbox to \\hsize\{\}\\vfill\\penalty-'10000000000}}
  end;
its_all_over:=false;
exit:end;
```

where

```
      tail_append(new_glue(fill_glue));
```

implies, as you suspected, that fill glue is added by the primitive.